# Is there official list of IP addresses/ranges of GoogleAssociationService?

Tags: android, android-app-links

In order to make our Android App Links work in our staging environment (which is behind corporate VPN), I would need to have a list or range of IP addresses that Google (GoogleAssociationService) uses to verify the host association, located at:

`https://<HOST>/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

Does anyone know an official list of IPs that we can whitelist? The best I found so far is:

- a couple of IPs here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239724946
- and this list which I don't know if is related to the service I am interested in: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do the trick by whitelisting the Google's ASN: `15169`. That was the best criterion that I found in Cloudflare. All the requests to `https://<HOST>/.well-known/assetlinks.json` were coming from there.